# In C# is there any difference between += and =+?

Tags: c#

If I go

```
variable1 =+ variable2
variable1 += variable2
```

I get the same result for variable1.

So is there any difference?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The difference is that your observation is not correct and `variable1 =+ variable2` does not add variable2 to variable1, but rather sets variable1 equal to variable2. The line is *really* `variable1 = +variable2`, or simply `variable1 = variable2`.

Consider this code

```
int a = 10;
int b = 20;

a =+ b;
a += b;
```

At the end of this process, `a` equals 40. It is intialized to 10, `b` is initialized to 20, `a` is set equal to `b`, and then `b` gets added to `a`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is a difference.

```
int x = 0; 

x += 1; --> x = x + 1; (you are adding 1 to x)

x =+ 1; --> x = +1; (you are assigning x a value)
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using a [toy example](http://ideone.com/2Olra) I show them as different.

- In the case of `variable1 =+ variable2` you're effectively computing

  ```
  variable1 = 0 + variable2
  ```

  or simply

  ```
  variable1 = variable2
  ```
- In the case of `variable1 += variable2` you're effectively computing

  ```
  variable1 = variable1 + variable2
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it's best to state that there is no =+ operator in C#.  But you can use a unary + to indicate a positive number (always redundant, but included for completeness).

And for completeness of this answer, x += y is the same as x = x + y.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the same result probably because you are running both on the same time as below.

```
        int One = 50;
        int Two = 65;
        One += Two;
        Two =+ One;
        Console.WriteLine(One);
        Console.WriteLine(Two);
```

both lines will give me the same result because int One is already = One + Two and then after that you are assigning One to Two.